# How to get display resolution (screen size)?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

How to get display resolution in XNA/Monogame ? 
I tried these on my monitor (1600x900):

The below give me 800,600

```
//1.
GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width
GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height

//2.
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width
graphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height

//3.
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height

//4.
foreach (DisplayMode dm in GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dm.Width);
    Console.WriteLine(dm.Height);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders you are right , my bad

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
_ScreenWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
_ScreenHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

extra references: System.Drawing ,  System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

If the application start in full screen, this may work:

```
Vector2 resolution = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
```

Comment: you cant start it in full screen if you cant calculate the screens size in the first place, i answered my own question btw

Comment: Nice, you could try this as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195024.aspx

Comment: `this.graphics.IsFullScreen = true;` this actually doesn't work, some people say its xbox only

Comment: it does work.  You have to do this:           graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
           graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 960;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();